# What movie has a spaceship with spikes on the front impaling a ship returning to earth?

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a kid, during the mid 90's, I once watched the first minutes of a sci-fi movie that scared me quite a bit back then.

From what I recall the movie was about a small group of people piloting a spaceship as they were returning to Earth after some kind of mission.

As they were somewhere between Mars and Jupiter they encountered a huge abandoned ship moving towards them. With an extreme manoeuvre the crew managed to avoid the drifting ship that soon changed its direction, hitting the small ship with its front spikes.

The ship was composed of 4-5 square blocks and it had long, narrow spikes on the front, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Aside from the spikes and the number of modules, that looks like the ship from 2001: A Space Odyssey.

Comment: Discovery in 2001 had a large sphere at the front and a somewhat wedge-shaped engine module at the rear.  Other than aspect ratio they are not very similar.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - that's why I said aside from the spikes - in 2001, there were no spikes, only a big ball.  And I kind of didn't care enough to bother explaining myself more fully.  The drawing looks like the middle section of the ship from 2001 is the basic point.

Comment: Did you try finding it on this [starship comparison chart](http://dirkloechel.deviantart.com/art/Size-Comparison-Science-Fiction-Spaceships-398790051)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am almost positive that the movie you're talking about it is [**Project Shadowchaser III**](http://gb.imdb.com/title/tt0114192/)

[image]

Comment: Just watched it and it's definitely the right one! Thank you! I made a few screenshots where it's possible to see the spaceship better [link](http://imgur.com/a/ujiGS).

Comment: Awesome!!! Glad I could help! I had been looking for this movie for years and your post finally led me to the right path to finding it.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a scene from the TV show "Firefly" or the movie "Serenity".

Though, from your doodle, the movie that you are thinking about sounds like the remake of "Dune".
[image: A Highliner from Dune.]

Comment: Firefly [premiered in 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_%28TV_series%29) so it can not be the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Serenity is a [2005 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_%28film%29) so it can not be the answer.

Comment: It does seem to resemble the liners from the Dune miniseries, however it was [released in 2000](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Herbert%27s_Dune), so it's probably not that either, unless the OP got the timeframe wrong. There isn't anything really scary in the beginning of the series, save for maybe when Paul is tested with the box by the bene gesserit.

Comment: 'That sounds like a scene from the TV show "Firefly" or the movie "Serenity".' - could you elaborate which scene in particular you are thinking of?

Comment: OP says the body of the ship is "square blocks".

Comment: @OrganicMarble The strange thing is that the OP drew rectangular blocks.  Maybe he doesn't know what squares are.

Answer (score 3):

The plot and ship description remind me of the sf/horror film [*Lifeforce* (1985)](http://www.willysvaults.com/MovieReviews/LifeForce.html), where a British space expedition to Halley’s Comet discovers an alien ship, although some of the details differ.

[image: *Lifeforce* alien ship]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the [Sulaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulaco_%28fictional_spacecraft%29)?  It's kind of blocky and has spikes out the front.  Don't remember it ramming any other ships though.

[image]

Comment: I doubt it's the ship from Aliens. They never rammed anyone.

Comment: As I mentioned.